# Python- Can use the mailing in attachment in a plain project but not in a class

Tags: python

I am picking a file from my Windows folder and I am trying to send it through gmail.
     This code works fine when it is executed in a separate python program  but I am unable to use the same program inside a class.

```
import smtplib
import base64

filename = str("JDI Offline.txt").split('\\')[-1:][0]
filepath = "C:\Windows\JDI Offline.txt"

fo = open(filepath, "rb")
filecontent = fo.read()
fo.close()
encodedcontent = base64.b64encode(filecontent)
sender = 'vusvarshil@gmail.com'
receiver = 'vusvarshil@gmail.com'

marker = "AUNIQUEMARKER"

body = """
Test to send attatchment
"""

part1 = """From: From Varshil<vusvarshil@gmail.com>
To:me
Subject: Sending attatchment
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=%s
--%s
""" % (marker, marker)

part2 = """Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding:8bit

%s
--%s
""" % (body, marker)

part3 = """Content-Type:multipart/mixed; name=\"%s\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64
Content-Disposition: attatchment; filepath=%s

%s
--%s--
""" % (filename, filepath, encodedcontent, marker)
message = part1 + part2 + part3

try:
    mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    mail.ehlo()
    mail.starttls()
    mail.login('vusvarshil@gmail.com', 'xxxxxxxx')
    mail.sendmail('vusvarshil@gmail.com', 'vusvarshil@gmail.com', message)
    print "Mail Sent successfully"
except Exception:
    print "Error"
```

When I use this code in a class i get a blank mail.I have attached the screenshots

[Program of program when used inside a class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ixCn.png)
[Program of program when used without a class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ref8L.png)

class sendmail:
      def send_mail():
    import smtplib
    import base64

```
filename = str("JDI Offline.txt").split('\\')[-1:][0]
filepath = "C:\Windows\JDI Offline.txt"

fo = open(filepath, "rb")
filecontent = fo.read()
fo.close()
encodedcontent = base64.b64encode(filecontent)
sender = 'vusvarshil@gmail.com'
receiver = 'vusvarshil@gmail.com'

marker = "AUNIQUEMARKER"

body = """
Test to send attatchment
"""

part1 = """From: From Varshil<vusvarshil@gmail.com>
To:me
Subject: Sending attatchment
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=%s
--%s
""" % (marker, marker)

part2 = """Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding:8bit

%s
--%s
""" % (body, marker)

part3 = """Content-Type:multipart/mixed; name=\"%s\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64
Content-Disposition: attatchment; filepath=%s

%s
--%s--
""" % (filename, filepath, encodedcontent, marker)
message = part1 + part2 + part3

try:
    mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    mail.ehlo()
    mail.starttls()
    mail.login('vusvarshil@gmail.com', 'xxxxxxxx')
    mail.sendmail('vusvarshil@gmail.com', 'vusvarshil@gmail.com', message)
    print "Mail Sent successfully"
except Exception:
    print "Error"
ob=sendmail()
ob.send_email()
```

Someone please tell what is the problem.

Comment: What is OOPS and where is it being used here?

Comment: So you are asking about your code that doesn't work, but then show us a different working version? What are we supposed to do with that?

Comment: I am sorry for the misunderstanding. What I am saying is when I use this code without a class I get the email with attachment but when i use it in class I get a blank email. Can you explain Why is that happening?

Comment: This doesn't look like code that should be in a class.

Comment: @VarshilShah Can you show us your broken code?

Comment: A-ha! These were actually two separate code snippets, incorrectly formatted as a single one. Suddenly the question makes some sense. That said, you (@VarshilShah) will have to fix the indentation in the 2nd snippet.

Comment: Sorry I am new to stack overflow so I am doing things haphazardly. Actually I want this code in a function which can be implemented in my class.

Comment: This code only broke when i used it In Class @Rawing

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem. This code did no work so I searched for a new code.I am posting the code here for future reference.
In the below code I am reading the data from a file and also appending the labels because that was my requirement. You can change the code as per your needs

```
# coding:utf-8



  import smtplib
  from email import MIMEMultipart
  from email import MIMEText
  from email import MIMEBase
  from email import encoders

  class classname:
  def fname(self):
    fromaddr = "mshah9900@gmail.com"
    toaddr = "vusvarshil@gmail.com"

    msg = MIMEMultipart.MIMEMultipart()

    msg['From'] = fromaddr
    msg['To'] = toaddr
    msg['Subject'] = "SUBJECT OF THE EMAIL"

    body = "TEXT YOU WANT TO SEND"

    msg.attach(MIMEText.MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

    filename = "JDI Offline.txt"
    fo = open("C:\Windows\JDI Offline.txt", "rb")

    length = len(fo.readlines())
    fo.close()
    fo = open("C:\Windows\JDI Offline.txt", "rb")

    filecontent = ""

    arr = ["Company name", "Contact person name", "Email", "Contact no.", "Address_Line_1", "Address_Line_2",
           "Address_Line_3", "City", "Pincode", "State", "Country", "PanCard No.", "Model", "Size", "Device Name",
           "Serial Number", "MediaType", "Interface type", "OS", "Ip address", "Registered date", "Registered Time"]
    for x in range(0,length):
             filecontent += arr[x] + ": " + fo.readline().lstrip().rstrip() + "\n"



    #     fo.close()

    filecontent += """\n
Additional content

"""

    fo.close()
    #print filecontent


    attachment = open("C:\Windows\JDI Offline.txt", "rb")
    # attachment += "hello"

    part = MIMEBase.MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
    part.set_payload((filecontent))
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)

    msg.attach(part)

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(fromaddr, "xxxxxxxx")
    text = msg.as_string()
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
    server.quit()

    cn=classname()
    cn.fname()
```